# Site Responsivo com jQuery

Tags: jquery, css3

Galera estou em duvida é melhor fazer site responsivo usando media queries ou jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples, com CSS e seguindo algumas regras, jQuery é apenas uma biblioteca do javascript então ele não vai definir o estilo da página, o que eu recomendo é usar medidas com % em vez de pixels pois vai se ajustar a tela e não uma medida fixa, usar a meta tag viewport para a melhor visualização do seu site em alguns dispositivos, e as media-query você pode especificar estilos, por exemplo @media screen específica o CSS para monitores, @media print para impressoras, @media (max-width: 480px) para telas menores como um celular por exemplo.